# How to create animation top view when bottom view up in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I need to create animation when user slide from bottom and top view also reflect and merge the view.

I used bottomsheet and topbottomsheet but no luck.

Also I tried motion layout for doing this but not giving expected result.

Here is the sample code :

```
topBehaviour =  TopSheetBehavior.from(cl_pickup_drop);

        
        slidingLayoutInital = findViewById(R.id.slidingLayoutInital);
        behaviorInitial = BottomSheetBehavior.from(slidingLayoutInital);

        behaviorInitial.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                Log.d("SHUBHAMNEWS",newState+"");
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
                    
                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            cl_pickup_drop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            searchModeClicked = PlaceSearchListFragment.PlaceSearchMode.DROP.getOrdinal();
                            openPickupDropSearchUI(PlaceSearchListFragment.PlaceSearchMode.PICKUP_AND_DROP);
                            behaviorInitial.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                            cl_pickup_drop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });


                } else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                    slidingLayoutInital.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

                int[] locationOnScreen = new int[2];
                bottomSheet.getLocationOnScreen(locationOnScreen);
                double newvalue = 1.0 - (slideOffset+0.2);

                Log.d(
                        "SHUBHAM slideOffset",
                        slideOffset+"--"+newvalue + "--"+cl_pickup_drop.getMeasuredHeight()
                );

                if(slideOffset == 0.0){
                    //slidingLayoutInital.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(100);
                    vvCouponCode.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(700);
                    llSetWhereTo.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(700);
                }else if(slideOffset==1){
                    relDestinationWhereTo.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_menu_item_color_black));
                    relSourceWhereTo.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_menu_item_color_f7_r));
                }else{
                    vvCouponCode.animate().alpha((float) newvalue).setDuration(700);
                    llSetWhereTo.animate().alpha((float) newvalue).setDuration(700);
                   // slidingLayoutInital.animate().alpha(0.5f).setDuration(100);
                }


                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //int mVal =  cl_pickup_drop.getMeasuredHeight() - (locationOnScreen[1]);
                        int mVal =  cl_pickup_drop.getMeasuredHeight() - (locationOnScreen[1]);
                        double calcualtePerce = (screenHeight / 100.0f) * 22;

                        if(initialMyLocationBtn.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                            calcualtePerce = calcualtePerce + (screenHeight / 100.0f) * 4;
                        }
                        if(relativeLayoutPoolInfoBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                            calcualtePerce = calcualtePerce + (screenHeight / 100.0f) * 4;
                        }

                        double mValWithPlus = mVal + calcualtePerce;
                        //Log.d("HomeBehaviour FINAL1",String.valueOf(cl_pickup_drop.getMeasuredHeight()));
                        //Log.d("HomeBehaviour FINAL2",String.valueOf(locationOnScreen[1]));
                        //Log.d("HomeBehaviour FINAL3",String.valueOf(mVal));
                        Log.d("HomeBehaviour FINAL+50",String.valueOf(mValWithPlus));

                        if(mValWithPlus > cl_pickup_drop.getMeasuredHeight()){
                            topBehaviour.setPeekHeight((int) cl_pickup_drop.getMeasuredHeight());
                        }else{
                            topBehaviour.setPeekHeight((int) mValWithPlus);
                        }

                        cl_pickup_drop.requestLayout();
                        bottomSheet.requestLayout();
                        // Code here will run in UI thread
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Please help!

https://github.com/carlos-mg89/TopSheetBehavior

Attached sample video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka9atmtg1thydf9/WhatsApp%20Video%202022-08-13%20at%201.10.55%20PM.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Create anim folder inside your res folder and copy this four files :

slide_in_bottom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"/>
```

slide_out_bottom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0" 
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_in_top.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

slide_out_top.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

When you click on image view call:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_bottom);
```

When you click on original place call:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_top, R.anim.slide_out_top);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it will work only for first time. We need to manage both scrolling when user slide from bottom , top view also reflect

Comment: pass it in a function

Comment: are you able to do that? i will pay you!

Comment: Ok This is my email - ayush2202ksr@gmail.com Share the github code

Comment: @ayushjain next time you post a ChatGPT answer *read* it, for obvious .... incompatibilities with reality

Comment: ok sir @panagiotis-kanavos... after confirmation only i will post it

Comment: No, stop trying to cheat otherwise you'll get banned. [ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1). Fake answers harm others and waste the time of people that have to clean up. Quite often they're so bad they cause *you* more harm than others

Comment: ok sir @panagiotis-kanavos...  will try to be less dependent on AI and will more dependent on my experience and knowledge...... yes sir you are right in this scenario....